# Count if one column contains and unique in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif, array-formulas

I'm trying to figure out how to count unique values in one column, where another column contains a certain value. For example, I want to count the unique values where Column 2 = `yes`. So the result should be **4** for this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
value1      yes
value2      yes
value2      no
value2      no
value3      yes
value3      yes
value4      yes
value5      no
```

I can figure this out: `=COUNTIF(B="yes")` but nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this array formula

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B10="Yes",IF(A2:A10<>"",MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0))),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> so that you get curly brackets like { and } around the formula

Answer (score 1):

Simplest may be with a PivotTable (Excel 2013):

[image: SO28583994 example]

Comment: Good answer, I didn't understand the link between value and the yes/no, but now I see..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with countif, by using

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1;A1)
```

supposing your "first" value is on A1 and filling the formula down. It extends the range as you fill down, so first value gets counted as 1 and if there is another hit downwards it gets counted >=2 so if you want to get result as YES or NO then you can add if function as follows -

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1;A1)<2;"YES";"NO")
```

You should get result like this

```
a   YES
b   YES
c   YES
s   YES
v   YES
b   NO
x   YES
s   NO
a   NO
d   YES
v   NO
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I'm literally looking for the output *4*

Comment: So you want to count the YES answers from a certain range? `=countif(A:A;"YES")` will that suffice?

Comment: Of course you need to change A:A range to what is your value range.

Comment: I count YES value where the valueN is unique. So I count *value1, value2,value3 & value4* once (but not their duplicates) and I **do not** count valu5 as it is a no

Comment: Well first of all, you need to get the unique ones, and that you can get by using the formula in answer, then count the yes with `countif(A:A;"YES")`

Comment: Oh, missed that detail - why you don't count value5?